# Heroku Postgres: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2, heroku-postgres

I am connecting to my postgres that is hosted on heroku from my raspberry pi however whenever I try to run a query using `psycopg2` I get nothing but errors. I have googled the error a bunch but none of it is really related. Any help would be appreciated.(I redacted connection info for obvious reasons)

**My Code:**

```py
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect("""dbname={REDACTED}
 host={REDACTED}
 port={REDACTED}
 user={REDACTED}
 password={REDACTED}
 sslmode=require
""")
cursor = connection.cursor()

data = cursor.fetchone()
print("Connection Established With: ", data)

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

The Error:
`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch`

Comment: The error message is correct. You never executed a query on the cursor so there is nothing to return.